# adding float openCV3.0

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I actually have a problem on openCV3.0.
I used 12 gabor filters(12 differents orientation) on 1 image and stocked them.
Now I want to add all those images and then divide by 12 each value to obtain the mean of the 12 filters. 
Because those image are RGB, I have to work on each channel separatly.
The problem is : when I add all the values, I obtain values > 12 while all the values are between 0 and 1.

The part of the code bugged :

```
for (i = 0; i < gaborV.size(); ++i) { //gaborV contain the 12 gabor filters
    std::vector<cv::Mat> vec_split; //I split because of the 3 channels
    cv::split(gaborV[i], vec_split);
    for (int k = 0; k < imgCol.rows; ++k) {
        for (int j = 0; j < imgCol.cols; ++j) {
            if (k == 1 && j == 1)
                std::cout << mat_X.at<float>(k, j) << "    " << vec_split[0].at<float>(k, j) << std::endl;
            mat_X.at<float>(k, j) += vec_split[0].at<float>(k, j);
            mat_Y.at<float>(k, j) += vec_split[1].at<float>(k, j);
            mat_Z.at<float>(k, j) += vec_split[2].at<float>(k, j);

        }
    }
}
```

and mat_X, mat_Y and mat_Z are created as follow :
`mat_X = mat_Y = mat_Z = cv::Mat(cvSize(imgColNormalize.cols, imgColNormalize.rows), CV_32FC1, cvScalar(0.));`

As I said, all values in vec_split are between 0 and 1, but when I'm out of the loop, mat_X, mat_Y and mat_Z contain values > 12..
The output of the cout I used :

```
0  0.507358
1.54751  0.496143
3.00963  0.528832
4.53887 0.465426
... and at the end I have 15.9459
```

And i don't understand since 0 + 0.507358 != 1.54751; 1.54751 + 0.496143 != 3.00963 ...

Do someone understand the problem?

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
mat_X = mat_Y = mat_Z = cv::Mat(cvSize(imgColNormalize.cols,    
                         imgColNormalize.rows), CV_32FC1, cvScalar(0.));
```

The way you initialise these arrays results in all three `cv::Mat` objects referencing the same data. Only one `Mat` is created and so your code increments the values in this array three times.

For info, OpenCV uses a reference counting mechanism with `cv::Mat` and the assignment operator simply creates a new reference to existing data. If you wanted to create a genuine deep-copy of a `cv::Mat`, you would need to use `cv::Mat::clone()`.

So, instead, initialise like so:

```
mat_X = cv::Mat(cvSize(imgColNormalize.cols, imgColNormalize.rows), CV_32FC1, cvScalar(0.));
mat_Y = cv::Mat(cvSize(imgColNormalize.cols, imgColNormalize.rows), CV_32FC1, cvScalar(0.));
mat_Z = cv::Mat(cvSize(imgColNormalize.cols, imgColNormalize.rows), CV_32FC1, cvScalar(0.));
```

An excerpt from [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d6/d6d/tutorial_mat_the_basic_image_container.html#gsc.tab=0) copied below for posterity:

[image: opencvdoc]

Comment: You guy rock more than a little! Effectively, that was the problem and that was something I didn't know... I will go to bed tonight less ignorant!
Thanks again!.